# What's wrong when iterating HTMLElement attributes

Tags: javascript

I had a problem when iterate `attributes` of a `HTMLElement`. Here is a simple function that create a HTMLElement contains 3 custom attribute:

```
function createAttrs() {
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        a = document.createAttribute('a'),
        b = document.createAttribute('b'),
        c = document.createAttribute('c');
    a.nodeValue = 'a';
    b.nodeValue = 'b';
    c.nodeValue = 'c';
    div.setAttributeNode(a);
    div.setAttributeNode(b);
    div.setAttributeNode(c);
    return div;
};

var element = createAttrs();
```

So `element` is equal to `<div a='a' b='b' c='c'></div>`.

Then I iterated `element.attributes` like this:

```
[].forEach.call(element.attributes, function(attr) {
    console.log(attr.name);
    element.removeAttribute(attr.name);
});
```

It's so weird that the devTool of Chrome just print `a` and `c`!

Where is `b`?

After that I typed `element` in the devTool, and it printed `<div b='b'></div>`.

It looks like the iterator just skip attribute `b`!

But when I remove `element.removeAttribute(attr.name);`, devTool print `a`,`b`,`c` as expected.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: you are removing the attrib before the next one comes up, so attribs[1] becomes attribs[0] as it goes to attribs[1]. reverse, setTimeout, or slice to fix.

Comment: You are changing collection while iterating over it. Generally that's bad idea. Try to copy the collection `[].slice.call(element.attributes).forEach()` beforehand.

Comment: Got it, I thought `attributes` would be cached by `forEach`... Thanks a lot :-)